# How do I get current route in onMounted on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When reloading page, I want to get current route. Sadly `route.name` is `undefined`, `router.currentRoute` is `RefImpl` object, which has correct route with `'/team'` inside. `router.currentRoute.value` is just root `'/'`, not `'/team'`, as expected. Is it possible to get correct value from `RefImpl`?

```
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  name: 'Canvas',
  components: { Ring2, Map },
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const route = useRoute()

    onMounted(() => {

      console.log(route.name) //undefined
      console.log(router.currentRoute) //RefImpl with correct value ('/team')
      console.log(router.currentRoute.value) // route is '/'
      const rawObject = {...router.currentRoute}
      console.log(rawObject) // value is '/'
      ...
```

Router is set up like this:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/team',
    name: 'Team',
    component: () => import('../views/Team.vue')
  },
   ...
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happens because the router hasn't yet completely resolved the initial navigation when you refresh the page, so `route` refers to the default (`/`) initially in `onMounted`.

Vue Router's [`isReady()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#isReady) returns a `Promise` that resolves when the router has completed the initial navigation, so your `onMounted` hook can `await` that `Promise` before trying to read `route.path`:

```js
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    const router = useRouter()

    onMounted(async () => {
      await router.isReady() 
      console.log('route.path', route.path)
    })
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-current-route?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FRouteLabel.vue)

Comment: Worth noting, this is also the earliest you can access the router meta. This is useful if you need to, say, hide the navbar until you know if the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the composable function useRoute :

```
import {
   useRoute
} from 'vue-router'
import {
   computed
} from 'vue'


setup() {
   const route = useRoute();

   const path = computed(() => route.path)
}
```

Comment: Sadly not getting result that i want, when i refresh or go to http://localhost:8080/team, computed value still gives me '/' as a path