# How to access current route name from App.vue in Vue 3 script setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-script-setup

I'm having trouble with getting current route name in App.vue in Vue3 script setup.

I would like to get the current route name and check if it matches some conditions.

The route is /login.
and the file where I wrote codes to check the route is App.vue.

First, I tried `router.currentRoute.value.name`, which is supposed to return the current route name.
But all I got was "/", instead of "login".
When I write this code in template, it shows the current route ("login").
Also when I write this code in Login.vue (the file `RouterView` is showing),
it shows the current route name.

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { RouterView, useRouter, useRoute } from "vue-router";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation.vue";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";
import { onMounted } from "vue";


const navigationDisabled = ref(null);
const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();


const checkRoute = () => {
  if (
    router.currentRoute.value.name === "login" ||
    router.currentRoute.value.name === "register" ||
    router.currentRoute.value.name === "forgot-password"
  ) {
    navigationDisabled.value = true;
    // console.log(router.currentRoute.value.name);
    return;
  }
  navigationDisabled.value = false;
};

onMounted(() => {
  checkRoute();
})

console.log(router.currentRoute.value.path);

</script>

<template>
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="app">
      <Navigation />
      <RouterView />
      <Footer />
      <p>{{ route.name }}</p>  //This works.
      <p>{{ router.currentRoute.value.name }}</p> //This also works.
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I also tried `route.name`, which showed the same result as the first one.

How can I access the current route name from App.vue?

Comment: Try using `{{ router.currentRoute }}` in template to show is as JSON. Maybe it's not "name".

Comment: You're checking for the route in the root component when vue-router is still processing the route navigation (to the login or other component).  A solution would be to use `await router.isReady()` as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70603018/6225326)

Comment: The router object is reactive, so that's why it works ok in the template. It rerenders to show the correct value which comes very quickly after mounting.

Comment: Generally navigationDisabled should be a computed. You'd need to react to route changes anyway, correct?

Comment: @Dimava Thank you for your help! It was just the root component was loaded before loading the child component.

Comment: @yoduh Thank you so much! I understand how it works better. It all worked!

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for your help! I see, I'll see more about computed. Apparently, the problem was the root component checking the route before the route navigation is done.